# Solving 2-dimensional recurrence matrix of homogenous polynomials

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations

In $2012$, Rajkumar [presented](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.5881.pdf) an interesting simplification of Apéry's theorem, i.e., that $\zeta(3)$ is irrational, where $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function. I am trying to understand his proof, but I severely lack knowledge on solving 2-dimensional recurrence relations in multiple homogeneous polynomials. In particular, he began by defining
$$
f(i,j)=i^3+2i^2j+2ij^2+j^3, \\
g(i,j)=i^3-2i^2j+2ij^2-j^3.
$$
He then constructed the recurrence relation
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
f(i,j) & g(0,j) \\
f(0,j) & g(i,j)
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
u_{i-1,j}\\
u_{i-1,j-1}
\end{array}\right)
=
f(i,0)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
u_{i,j}\\
u_{i,j-1}
\end{array}\right)
$$
and showed that for integers $i, j \geq 1$ it has a rational valued solution $u_{i,j}$ for certain boundary conditions.

I would *really* like to understand how one solves such recurrence relations, but unfortunately after searching extensively on the internet for related articles or tutorials I have found nothing. I understand how basic recurrence relations work, but in this case I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do and what theory I can apply.

Can anyone give me any pointers?